# Can you write data to NFC tag in smartphone?

Tags: android, ios, nfc, iot, rfid

Can anyone tell me whether it is possible to write to the NFC tag in a smartphone?

I know that's not the usual application and I could write the (small amount of) data to an app on the phone as well but I'd like to implement this in a way that doesn't require an app installed on the phone.

I have read answers to some more application-specific questions here regarding the use of a (specific) smartphone as an NFC tag, but I have a very limited understanding of RFID technology in smartphones and none of these answers have helped me answer my very simple question.
For my application I'd need to be able to write the data to any smartphone, or at least the majority of devices currently in use, without the "active participation" of any SW on the phone.

So if anyone could tell me whether or not this is even possible, I'd greatly appreciate that :) Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Android smartphones any developer make the phone behave like a Type 4 NFC tag with host card emulation.

With iOS only Apple can make the phone behave like an NFC Tag (with Apple Wallet)

So what you want is not really possible.

You might be achieve what you want with something like PassKit https://passkit.com/ as that allows you to store "passes" in Google and Apple wallets which have NFC capability.

Though you might be better of with QR code as they can be read on all devices with the camera and show on screen by your apps.

Comment: Man, thank you so much! You've helped me a lot!